# Kubernetes finding log for pod

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

Trying to install Elastic Stack

Hi I have connected to a cluster via gitlab self hosted ee.13.2.2

I am using gitlab and I installed the ingress, prometheus, cert manager and the runner but when I try to install Elastic stack it will not install. Does anyone know where I can look to find the correct logs to figure out why it will not install?

The error says:

Something went wrong while installing Elastic Stack

```
Operation failed. Check pod logs for install-elastic-stack for more details.
```

[Error-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7we0.png)
[Error-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b7Tf.png)

```
+ export 'HELM_HOST=localhost:44134'
+ helm init --client-only
+ tiller -listen localhost:44134 -alsologtostderr
Creating /root/.helm 
Creating /root/.helm/repository 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /root/.helm/plugins 
Creating /root/.helm/starters 
Creating /root/.helm/cache/archive 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
[main] 2020/08/15 19:22:35 Starting Tiller v2.16.9 (tls=false)
[main] 2020/08/15 19:22:35 GRPC listening on localhost:44134
[main] 2020/08/15 19:22:35 Probes listening on :44135
[main] 2020/08/15 19:22:35 Storage driver is ConfigMap
[main] 2020/08/15 19:22:35 Max history per release is 0
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts 
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /root/.helm.
Not installing Tiller due to 'client-only' flag having been set
+ helm repo add elastic-stack https://charts.gitlab.io
"elastic-stack" has been added to your repositories
+ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Skip local chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "elastic-stack" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete.
+ helm upgrade elastic-stack elastic-stack/elastic-stack --install --atomic --cleanup-on-fail --reset-values --version 3.0.0 --set 'rbac.create=true,rbac.enabled=true' --namespace gitlab-managed-apps -f /data/helm/elastic-stack/config/values.yaml
[tiller] 2020/08/15 19:22:44 getting history for release elastic-stack
[storage] 2020/08/15 19:22:44 getting release history for "elastic-stack"
Release "elastic-stack" does not exist. Installing it now.
[tiller] 2020/08/15 19:22:44 preparing install for elastic-stack
[storage] 2020/08/15 19:22:44 getting release history for "elastic-stack"
[tiller] 2020/08/15 19:22:44 rendering elastic-stack chart using values
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch/templates/podsecuritypolicy.yaml" is empty. Skipping.
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch-curator/templates/role.yaml" is empty. Skipping.
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch/templates/role.yaml" is empty. Skipping.
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch-curator/templates/rolebinding.yaml" is empty. Skipping.
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch-curator/templates/hooks/job.install.yaml" is empty. Skipping.
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch/templates/rolebinding.yaml" is empty. Skipping.
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch/templates/ingress.yaml" is empty. Skipping.
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch-curator/templates/psp.yml" is empty. Skipping.
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch/templates/configmap.yaml" is empty. Skipping.
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch/templates/serviceaccount.yaml" is empty. Skipping.
2020/08/15 19:22:44 info: manifest "elastic-stack/charts/elasticsearch-curator/templates/serviceaccount.yaml" is empty. Skipping.
[tiller] 2020/08/15 19:22:44 performing install for elastic-stack
[tiller] 2020/08/15 19:22:44 executing 1 crd-install hooks for elastic-stack
[tiller] 2020/08/15 19:22:44 hooks complete for crd-install elastic-stack
[tiller] 2020/08/15 19:22:45 executing 1 pre-install hooks for elastic-stack
[tiller] 2020/08/15 19:22:45 hooks complete for pre-install elastic-stack
[storage] 2020/08/15 19:22:45 getting release history for "elastic-stack"
[storage] 2020/08/15 19:22:45 creating release "elastic-stack.v1"
[kube] 2020/08/15 19:22:45 building resources from manifest
[kube] 2020/08/15 19:22:45 creating 11 resource(s)
[kube] 2020/08/15 19:22:46 beginning wait for 11 resources with timeout of 5m0s
[kube] 2020/08/15 19:22:48 Pod is not ready: gitlab-managed-apps/elastic-stack-filebeat-h544s <= this line ran lots of times (100ish)
[tiller] 2020/08/15 19:27:46 warning: Release "elastic-stack" failed: timed out waiting for the condition
[storage] 2020/08/15 19:27:46 updating release "elastic-stack.v1"
[tiller] 2020/08/15 19:27:46 failed install perform step: release elastic-stack failed: timed out waiting for the condition
INSTALL FAILED
PURGING CHART
then eventually:
Successfully purged a chart!
Error: release elastic-stack failed: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Comment: Get the list of pods by running `kubectl get pods -A` and see if you have find the relevant pod.

Comment: Thanks Faheem, this is what i'm getting: gitlab-managed-apps   install-elastic-stack                                    0/1     Error. Then when I try to get logs from that pod: 
Error from server (NotFound): pods "install-elastic-stack" not found

Comment: Please do a describe on the pod and check events section at the bottom. Since it's 0/1, the pod never started and wouldn't have any logs.

Comment: Also check logs of the `gitlab-managed-apps` pod

Comment: Aha, I had to specify the namespace to access the pods logs. I will update my question with the log

Answer (score 1):

Please try running it again. Helm sometimes times out rather quickly. If it's failing consistently, look inside elastic-stack namespace. See which pods are not starting inside it and what errors are you getting there.

Comment: The only namespace is gitlab-managed-apps and kube-system. elastic stack is within the gitlab-managed-apps namespace. I did try to install it multiple times over a few days, thanks for trying to help. I even uninstalled some other applications to see if there was too many installed at once, but still no good, and they also reinstall fine.

Comment: You may want to post the issue and logs to git lab user forum for some guidance as well.